# Why do many SPI flash devices from different suppliers have specifically "25" at the beginning of their part number?

Tags: markings, nor-flash

There is some nomenclature that I understand for SPI flash devices that indicate the memory size. When looking at the packaging and ordering information, I can see the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Picture sources from their respective datasheets of the part number.

I'm not necessarily asking about the nomenclature but rather, **what's so special about the number *25* in particular and why do many suppliers have that specific number**? Is there an industry standard for this nomenclature? Is it purely marketing?

Comment: I think "25" means "serial NOR flash".  "35" is for serial NAND, "24" is for "two-wire serial EEPROM". "27", "28" and "29" are for "parallel flash" , 8-bit parallel flash memories. But I would be interested in real answer about these conventions.

Comment: @Ale..chenski 27 is the old ultraviolet erasable EPROMs. 28 is parallel EEPROM.

Comment: I can't seem to find any JEDEC standard for flash part number nomenclature. The Infineon [NOR Flash part number decoder](https://www.avnet.com/wps/wcm/connect/onesite/1f7cee95-b42e-4b9c-bd9d-7b4f3a72d911/Infineon-NOR-Flash-part-number-decoder.pdf?MOD=AJPERES&CVID=nzjO6BU&CVID=nzjO6BU) has a _Product / Interface_ column where some examples are 25 = SPI, 26 = HYPERBUS™ (serial), 28 = Octal (serial), 29 = Parallel, 38 = Octal (serial). I.e. Infineon use "28" for their SEMPER™ Functional safety octal serial NOR flash, which @GodJihyo said is also used for parallel EEPROM.